# SQL Server: Want to use variable in ORDER BY on UNION

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by, union

I read that this should be possible, but I am failing to make it work! I've tried setting the field name both ways - no dice.

```
USE RTIDatastore;
DECLARE @PAYE AS VARCHAR(20) = 'T6901' -- 'F1867' -- 'S860'
DECLARE @Product AS VARCHAR(20) = 'ADPFREEDOMAS2';
DECLARE @TaxYear AS CHAR(2) = '15';     -- NB No EMP data for FPS14s
DECLARE @EndPeriod AS INTEGER = 6;
DECLARE @OrderBy AS CHAR(1) = 'S';
DECLARE @OrderTest AS VARCHAR(10) = 'NINO'; -- 'Name';
-- this gets all the EMP records, and the first associated NI records (if any)
SELECT
   R.[EmployerPAYE]                                                AS PAYE
 , H.[ICR]                                                         AS ICR
 , E.[NINO]                                                        AS NINo
 , E.[Surname] + ', ' + E.[Forename]                               AS Name
 , E.[Surname]                              AS SurName          -- added for testing
 , E.[Forename]                             AS ForeName         -- added for testing
 , EMP.[EmploymentID]                                              AS EmploymentID
 , EMP.[ATT3_19_PayrollID]                                         AS ATT3_19_PayrollID     -- identifies EMP record
 , EMP.[ALC14_TaxCode]                                             AS ALC1_4_TaxCode
 , NI.[Employee_NI]                                                AS NI_PK
 , NI.[Emp2_NILetter]                                              AS EMP2_NILetter
FROM [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Header] H
 JOIN      [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employer]    R   ON H.[HeaderID] = R.[HeaderID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee]    E   ON R.[EmployerID] = E.[EmployerID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employment]  EMP ON E.[EmployeeID] = EMP.[EmployeeID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee_NI] NI  ON EMP.[EmploymentID] = NI.[EmploymentID_FK]
WHERE H.[SenderID] = @Product
 AND H.[MessageType] = 'FPS' + @TaxYear
 AND R.[EmployerPAYE] = @PAYE
 AND (NI.[Employee_NI] LIKE '%_NI_1' OR NI.[Employee_NI] IS NULL)
UNION
-- this gets any additional NI records
SELECT
   R.[EmployerPAYE]                                                AS PAYE
 , H.[ICR]                                                         AS ICR
 , E.[NINO]                                                        AS NINo
 , E.[Surname] + ', ' + E.[Forename]                               AS Name
 , E.[Surname]                              AS SurName
 , E.[Forename]                             AS ForeName
 , EMP.[EmploymentID]                                              AS EmploymentID
 , EMP.[ATT3_19_PayrollID]                                         AS ATT3_19_PayrollID     -- identifies EMP record
 , EMP.[ALC14_TaxCode]                                             AS ALC1_4_TaxCode
 , NI.[Employee_NI]                       AS NI_PK
 , NI.[Emp2_NILetter]                     AS EMP2_NILetter
FROM [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Header] H
 JOIN      [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employer]    R   ON H.[HeaderID] = R.[HeaderID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee]    E   ON R.[EmployerID] = E.[EmployerID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employment]  EMP ON E.[EmployeeID] = EMP.[EmployeeID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee_NI] NI  ON EMP.[EmploymentID] = NI.[EmploymentID_FK]
WHERE H.[SenderID] = @Product
 AND H.[MessageType] = 'FPS' + @TaxYear
 AND R.[EmployerPAYE] = @PAYE
 AND NI.[Employee_NI] NOT LIKE '%_NI_1'
-- generally Surname is safer than NINo or PayrollID, but not always!
--ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'N' THEN NINo
--              WHEN @OrderBy = 'P' THEN ATT3_19_PayrollID
--              ELSE Surname
--         END
--     , ICR
--     , EmploymentID
--     , NI_PK
ORDER BY @OrderTest -- Name
 --, NINo
 --, ATT3_19_PayrollID
 , ICR
 , EmploymentID
 , NI_PK
```

Both the above ORDER clauses fail, but this works fine:

```
ORDER BY Name
 --, NINo
 --, ATT3_19_PayrollID
 , ICR
 , EmploymentID
 , NI_PK
```

I need to put the code into a stored procedure, so I don't really want to have to write it out 3 times, for the possible different order requirements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can wrap your query into a new SELECT and apply order by to the overall results. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (

  -- Your original unioned query without order by here --

) T

ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: That works a treat, and is nice and simple too! Thanks to @Jaques for other suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

Cant do  order by directly with Parameter.. use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE [Condition] ORDER BY 
CASE @OrderByColumn
    WHEN Condition1 THEN Value1
    WHEN Condition2 THEN Value2
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this two ways: 'ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy
              WHEN 'N' THEN NINo
              WHEN 'P' THEN ATT3_19_PayrollID
              WHEN 'S' THEN Name
         END
     , ICR
     , EmploymentID
     , NI_PK     ' gives the error "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 76
Invalid column name 'Name'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: and 'ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy
              WHEN 'N' THEN NINo
              WHEN 'P' THEN ATT3_19_PayrollID
              WHEN 'S' THEN **SurName**
         END
     , ICR
     , EmploymentID
     , NI_PK     ' gives the error "Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: It may be because ur order by uses alias names. Try with what u have in select statement , Or use select query in insert into a #temp table and and use Order by with that temp table..

Comment: That is likely the reason - using the additional SELECT removes that issue, so I have gone that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can also execute the proc with an Exec and build your order by clause, but I think the conditional Order by that is demonstrated in the one answer is better, unless you want to specify the `order by` in a string.

```
DECLARE @PAYE AS VARCHAR(20) = 'T6901' -- 'F1867' -- 'S860'
DECLARE @Product AS VARCHAR(20) = 'ADPFREEDOMAS2';
DECLARE @TaxYear AS CHAR(2) = '15';     -- NB No EMP data for FPS14s
DECLARE @EndPeriod AS INTEGER = 6;
DECLARE @OrderBy AS CHAR(1) = 'S';
DECLARE @OrderTest AS VARCHAR(10) = 'NINO'; -- 'Name';
-- this gets all the EMP records, and the first associated NI records (if any)

DECLARE @SqlString nvarchar(max)
Select @SqlString = 'SELECT
   R.[EmployerPAYE]                                                AS PAYE
 , H.[ICR]                                                         AS ICR
 , E.[NINO]                                                        AS NINo
 , E.[Surname] + '', '' + E.[Forename]                               AS Name
 , E.[Surname]                              AS SurName          -- added for testing
 , E.[Forename]                             AS ForeName         -- added for testing
 , EMP.[EmploymentID]                                              AS EmploymentID
 , EMP.[ATT3_19_PayrollID]                                         AS ATT3_19_PayrollID     -- identifies EMP record
 , EMP.[ALC14_TaxCode]                                             AS ALC1_4_TaxCode
 , NI.[Employee_NI]                                                AS NI_PK
 , NI.[Emp2_NILetter]                                              AS EMP2_NILetter
FROM [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Header] H
 JOIN      [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employer]    R   ON H.[HeaderID] = R.[HeaderID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee]    E   ON R.[EmployerID] = E.[EmployerID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employment]  EMP ON E.[EmployeeID] = EMP.[EmployeeID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee_NI] NI  ON EMP.[EmploymentID] = NI.[EmploymentID_FK]
WHERE H.[SenderID] = @Product
 AND H.[MessageType] = ''FPS'' + @TaxYear
 AND R.[EmployerPAYE] = @PAYE
 AND (NI.[Employee_NI] LIKE ''%_NI_1'' OR NI.[Employee_NI] IS NULL)
UNION
-- this gets any additional NI records
SELECT
   R.[EmployerPAYE]                                                AS PAYE
 , H.[ICR]                                                         AS ICR
 , E.[NINO]                                                        AS NINo
 , E.[Surname] + '', '' + E.[Forename]                               AS Name
 , E.[Surname]                              AS SurName
 , E.[Forename]                             AS ForeName
 , EMP.[EmploymentID]                                              AS EmploymentID
 , EMP.[ATT3_19_PayrollID]                                         AS ATT3_19_PayrollID     -- identifies EMP record
 , EMP.[ALC14_TaxCode]                                             AS ALC1_4_TaxCode
 , NI.[Employee_NI]                       AS NI_PK
 , NI.[Emp2_NILetter]                     AS EMP2_NILetter
FROM [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Header] H
 JOIN      [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employer]    R   ON H.[HeaderID] = R.[HeaderID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee]    E   ON R.[EmployerID] = E.[EmployerID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employment]  EMP ON E.[EmployeeID] = EMP.[EmployeeID_FK]
 LEFT JOIN [RTIDatastore].[dbo].[Employee_NI] NI  ON EMP.[EmploymentID] = NI.[EmploymentID_FK]
WHERE H.[SenderID] = @Product
 AND H.[MessageType] = ''FPS'' + @TaxYear
 AND R.[EmployerPAYE] = @PAYE
 AND NI.[Employee_NI] NOT LIKE ''%_NI_1''
ORDER BY ' + @OrderTest + '
 , ICR
 , EmploymentID
 , NI_PK'

 exec sp_executesql @stmt = @sqlString, @params = N'@Product AS VARCHAR(20), @TaxYear AS CHAR(2), @EndPeriod AS INTEGER, @PAYE AS VARCHAR(20)', @Product = @Product, @TaxYear = @TaxYear, @EndPeriod = @EndPeriod, @PAYE = @PAYE
```